How to pass custom headers in the upgrade requests using a WebSocket client in my React App
I have tried using the native websocket library to initiate upgrade connection requests. However, my server requires the access token to be sent as a header.
Is there a way to pass access token as a custom header using the Websocket library, or is there any other alternative that I can use
I tried using socket io client but that doesn't give a proper solution as the custom header is not passed when the transport is set to 'websocket'

worth reading if you haven’t.
